# Does SqlConnection get disposed using this function

Tags: c#, dispose, sqlconnection

```
public CategorieEquipement Select(int NoType)
{
        SqlConnection cx = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLConnect"].Connection    String);
        SqlDataReader reader;

        CategorieEquipement lstCategorie = new CategorieEquipement();
        try
        {
            cx.Open();
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT_CategorieEquip", cx);
            com.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@where",NoType);
            reader = com.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                lstCategorie.CodeRef = reader["CodeRef"].ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("SELECT ERROR : " + ex.ToString());
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (cx != null)
            {
                cx.Close();
            }
        }
        return lstCategorie;
    }
}
```

My question is if I remove the finally block of code, will the garbage collector close the connection when disposing of the SQlConnection object?

I know it is a better practice to be explicit but my coworker doesn't agree .

Comment: Your coworker is wrong

Comment: why not wrap the `Sql Objects around a using(){}` to take advantage of auto disposing.. the GC is not always immediate either.. I agree with @Steve as well perhaps you need to not rely on your cow-worker giving you flawed advice / information

Comment: Why not leave it as it is, code seems perfectly fine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> will the garbage collector close the connection when disposing of the
>   SQlConnection object?

Garbage collector is not responsible for calling `Dispose` on an object, usually `Dispose` is called in the Finalizer, only then GC would be able to *properly* dispose the object.

One important thing to note is that you cannot predict when the garbage collection process will run, so it is always better to explicitly dispose objects *(which implements `IDisposable`)*.

As far as database connections are concerned the approach should be open as late as possible and close as early as possible.

In the case above `cx.Close();` should be enough, instead,  you can also call `cx.Dispose`, **But a better approach** would be to enclose the `SqlConnection` in [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) block.

That will translate into `try/finally` block and it will ensure the `SqlConnection` disposal.

Answer (score 1):

The garbage collection will dispose it, but since it is non-deterministic you don't know when it will do it.

C# provide the `using` structure to dispose unmanaged code and it is recommended to use it:

```
using (SqlConnection cx = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLConnect"].ConnectionString);)
{

}
```

Tell your co-workers they ought to wrap any instance of objects that implement the IDisposable interface in a `using` so that they will be disposed in a deterministic fashion to ensure a correct management of the application resources and avoid problems like memory leaks.